# Not able to get iwgetid when running NodeJS Script as daemon

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, debian, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I'm building a Raspberry PI3 web server where one of the pages should display the SSID of the wireless network my raspberry PI is currently connected to. To get that I'm using(in NodeJS):

```
require("child_process").exec('iwgetid',callback....)
```

it runs as expected if i execute script in SSH. However if i run this as service I get the following output in /var/log/syslog:

> Jul 30 16:21:10 raspberrypi2 index.js[11406]: Child process exited with error code ErrorCommand failed: iwgetid
>   Jul 30 16:21:10 raspberrypi2 index.js[11406]: /bin/sh: 1: iwgetid: not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path environment variable may be different when you run it as a service. Your first step is probably to try using the absolute path.

```
require("child_process").exec('/sbin/iwgetid',callback....)
```